# How can be bind data in listbox different-2 size in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

Is that possible to bind data in Listbox in different-2 size?

I want to display listbox binding data in following format with click and hold event in windows phone.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible.
You need to create two different DataTemplates and use a trick with [DataTemplateSelector](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/implementing-windows-phone-7-datatemplateselector-and-customdatatemplateselector)

Add a [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) to your project, and define a listbox as following:

```
<ListBox Source="{ set your binding here}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemsPannel>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      define your DataTemplates and dataTempleteSelectors here
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: please given me a complete example

Comment: i have some link of mp4 video in xml. also the xml store the information of video like video image, description, id etc. i am parse the xml and store data in list. now i am try to create a showcase to display only three video in above display image format.